# React Navigation v6 usePreventRemoveContext is undefined error

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

```
TypeError: (0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "@react-navigation/native").usePreventRemoveContext) is not a function. (In '(0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "@react-navigation/native").usePreventRemoveContext)()', '(0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "@react-navigation/native").usePreventRemoveContext)' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in NativeStackViewInner (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:420)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:87)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:46)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:419)
    in NativeStackView (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:72)
    in Unknown (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:71)
    in NativeStackNavigator (at App.js:19)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at App.js:18)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in hello_world(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
```

I am brand new to react-native and react navigation. I am trying to use react navigation v6 and am just running the getting started guide. I am getting this error that I have never seen before. I can run a few basic pages just fine. However, whenever I add navigation I get this unusual error. I have followed all of the guides to the best of my ability and created the original folder with the `npx react-native init` command. Here's a copy of my App.js file which is the only file that I have changed other than MainActivity.java, where I added the prerequiste onCreate function for React navigation v6. This is straight from their website: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/. I genuinely have no idea why this issue is occurring. Feel free to leave feedback if you need more information. All help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Sorry if the answer is obvious to anyone. I've tried searching anywhere else that I could find it and didn't. I also did my best to follow all the intros accurately and I think that I did. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you installed dependencies which are required ?

Comment: @Iva Yes, of course.

Answer (score 4):

This is some kind of compatibility issue. Fixed by `npm update`. Anyone who knows more feel free to elaborate, but the situation is resolved.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and running `npm update` also solved the issue.

Checking the lock file I noticed it updated this dependency "@react-navigation/elements". Is like you said, It's probably some kind of compatibility issue or bug fix.

Comment: In my case this error was resolved when I removed unused dependencies that I had added while experimenting with 3rd-party libraries. I also had to run `npm install` after

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when I rewrote a project from YouTube. I would have @react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11" installed, I would have installed an older version of "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6", and
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",. After that it worked.